# Does inheriting the Sprite class and use group in pygame makes the game faster?

Tags: pygame

Does it help the game's performance? Or should I just blit the images? In the pygame official documentary, it said "It (`pygame.sprite.Sprite`) is the base class for visible game objects." and "It (`pygame.sprite.Group`) is a simple container for Sprite objects." Now for example a bullet, I have two options:
1. inherit the class and add it to a group when something triggers 
or
2. don't inherit and create a list manually and add it to the list when something triggers.
What I think of a group, is it blits everything in the group. Then what's the difference between this and `screen.blit()` in each class? 
If there is no difference, then `pygame.surface.GroupSingle` really doesn't have any use. So I'm not sure what should I use 
 (U+1F937)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`pygame.sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) module make the code shorter and easier to understand and offer you features like `pygame.sprite.spritecollide`, `pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates` etc. The underlying code is highly optimized for use with the SDL 2 on which the pygame is based. However, there is no magic boost behind it. Parts of pygame are written in C/C++ (see [GitHub - pygame](https://github.com/pygame/pygame)
). So there is no python for-loop behind the scenes that calls `.blit` for each sprite. Drawing the sprites with a group is more efficient than drawing with a python `for`-loop and `blit`. Anyway, if you know what you are doing, you can write effective code without the `pygame.sprite` module.
[`pygame.surface.GroupSingle`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.GroupSingle) is not useless. It can be used like any other group and can be used with `pygame.sprite.spritecollide` etc.